# GTM will not work if there is already an event handler on the element?

Tags: google-tag-manager

Is it true: GTM will not work if there is already an event handler on the element?

For example, I want to configure button click tracking. But if it already in code page has another handler (script, addEventListener) on it, will GTM ignore my setup? It's right? If so, in what cases will GTM not record events?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not true. Google Tag Manager will work even when there is already an event handler attached. However it will not work if the function in that event handler suppresses event propagation.

For example, GTM will fail if you do something like this (example is using jQuery, but the same goes for plain JS):

```
$('a#toTop').on('click', function() {
  console.log("Link Clicked");
  return false;
});
```

because `return false` stops event propagation, which is a JS feature that GTM needs to work.

Google Tag Manager does not attach event handler to individual elements. Instead it attaches the event handler to the document itself. A click on an element then propagates upwards through the DOM, until it meets the document root and is handled by the respective event handler. If you do a return false the event does not travel upwards, and the GTM event handler will not work.

However if you do this properly - e.g. by using `event.preventDefault()` instead of return false - then GTM will work just fine. "Return false" is mostly an outdated way to suppress the default action of an element, and should not be used for that purpose anymore in any case.